# Setting dynamic image in android based on a string

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-resources

Consider I have two images image_name1.png, image_name2.png in drawable resources of android. Now I would like set image like below,

```
imageView.setImage(R.drawable.image_+"MyChoice"+.png);
```

where MyChoice can be name1 or name2 or some string

Is that possible, or do we have any solution to achieve that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to change the image of an ImageView based on some condition?

Comment: Are you set two images in single imageView??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do by uri

```
String uri = "@drawable/imname"; //imname without extension

int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName()); //get image  resource

Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource); // convert into drawble

imageView.setImageDrawable(res); // set as image
```

Answer (score 1):

`Resources.getIdentifier` does what you're looking for.

```
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("image_"+myChoice, "drawable", "com.myapp.mypackage");
if(resId == 0) {
    resId = R.drawable.default;
}
imageView.setImageResource(resId);
```

Comment: how can I use above snippet when drawable present in different versions like drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi but not present in drawable

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  What you can do is something like:

```
int images[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2};

imageView.setImage(images[mychoice]);
```

Or something similar with a hash table if you want to do strings instead of integer indexes.

As an aside-  you don't put the .png in the drawable name in code.  THe point of drawable is that you shouldn't need to know if its png, jpg, or even xml.

Comment: Hey @Gabe Sachan check the answer I upvoted, that's working for me

Answer (score 0):

there are two posibilties

1.

```
int  MyChoice=1 or 2;
`imageView.setImage(R.drawable.image_+MyChoice+.png);`
```

second is

```
int image=Integer.parseInt("R.drawable.image_"+MyChoice+".png");
imageView.setImage(image);
```